# How to get the center of a polygon in google maps v3?

Tags: google-maps, polygon, google-maps-api-3

It doesn't need to be 100% correct, it can be the center of the bounding rectangle.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Algorithm:

Run through all the points in the polygon. For all the points find;

- `x1`, the lowest `x` coordinate
- `y1`, the lowest `y` coordinate
- `x2`, the highest `x` coordinate
- `y2`, the highest `y` coordinate

You now have the bounding rectangle, and can work out the center using:

```
center.x = x1 + ((x2 - x1) / 2);
center.y = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / 2);
```

Comment: Well, i've found that in v2, I was able to do it just by calling polygon.getBounds().getCenter(), but I guess i'll have to do it your way. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea, that may work in v3 too. I havn't looked too closely at the Google Maps API. But this way does essentially that anyway.

Comment: It looks like Google forgot the `Polygon.getBounds()` method. It is available for `Circle` and `Rectangle`, but not for the `Polygon` class.

Comment: This will fail horrifically if the polygon crosses the international date line (example: Russia's international boundary).

Comment: As @Canuk stated, this will fail in certain circumstances. Ideally you want to use the mean of circular quantities, and not a arithmetic mean. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities

Answer (score 236):

[Matthew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081021/how-to-get-the-center-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3/3081078#3081078) is a good solution. However, when using the Google Maps API v3, you might want to pass each point of the polygon to a [`LatLngBounds`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) object through the `extend()` method, and then finally call the `getCenter()` method on the `LatLngBounds` object. Consider the following example:

```js
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var i;

// The Bermuda Triangle
var polygonCoords = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
  new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
  new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.757370),
  new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
];

for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
}

// The Center of the Bermuda Triangle - (25.3939245, -72.473816)
console.log(bounds.getCenter());
```

Comment: Wrapped up nicely here: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-extensions/source/browse/google.maps.Polygon.getBounds.js

Comment: Why is this the better solution? To me it seems that both solutions should always get to the same answer. Is this faster?

Comment: @Nicolas: Both will get to the same solution, but this is simpler to implement, relies on Googles API's and is more obvious what it does at a glance thanks to being shorter in code (4 lines at worst). Either method should have negligible runtime, so speed isn't an issue.

Comment: I getting the following Error with the above code. TypeError: a is undefined

Comment: Also, this is a better solution as it will take into account the curvature of the Earth. The trivial algorithm I posted will be a reasonable approximation for small areas, but if you are trying to work out the geographical centre of a region for instance, then this will give a better answer. The world isn't rectangular, only maps are.

Comment: @Nicolas - this answer is better because it deals with polygons that cross the international date line (e.g. Russia's international border). If you just take the min/max lon, as in the accepted answer, you'll get bizarre results sometimes.

Comment: This is good, unless your Polygon is of a "L" shape for example, in which case, the `bounds.getCenter()` will be off the Polygon.

Comment: Also worth the note that Bounds get's the top left and bottom right and then returns the center point of those. It does not always give you a visual center of a more complex polygon.

Answer (score 59):

you can extend the Polygon class with your own version of the missing function, let's call it my_getBounds() :

```
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.my_getBounds=function(){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
    this.getPath().forEach(function(element,index){bounds.extend(element)})
    return bounds
}
```

and than use it in code like this :

```
myPolygon.my_getBounds().getCenter()
```

... etc, it should be equivalent to the v2 behavior

Comment: Found this posting when doing a google search for the same issue..  This suggestion worked out perfectly for me! thanks..

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me. the `my_getBounds()` function is undefined when I try to call it on Polygon objects.

Comment: Upon further experimentation, this appears to be out-of-date compared to the newest iteration of Google Maps Javascript API v3. The Polygon class is now `google.maps.Data.Polygon`, and there's no `getPath()` method on the class.

Comment: This answer worked verbatim for me today (August 21, 2015) on google.maps.Polygon objects with no changes using the Google Maps API v3.

Comment: A smaller version of this on es6 `polygon.getPath().getArray().reduce((prev, curr) => prev.extend(curr), new google.maps.LatLngBounds());`

Answer (score 8):

Here is a custom function I wrote. Feel free to use it.

```
function polygonCenter(poly) {
    const vertices = poly.getPath();

    // put all latitudes and longitudes in arrays
    const longitudes = new Array(vertices.length).map((_, i) => vertices.getAt(i).lng());
    const latitudes = new Array(vertices.length).map((_, i) => vertices.getAt(i).lat());

    // sort the arrays low to high
    latitudes.sort();
    longitudes.sort();

    // get the min and max of each
    const lowX = latitudes[0];
    const highX = latitudes[latitudes.length - 1];
    const lowy = longitudes[0];
    const highy = longitudes[latitudes.length - 1];

    // center of the polygon is the starting point plus the midpoint
    const centerX = lowX + ((highX - lowX) / 2);
    const centerY = lowy + ((highy - lowy) / 2);

    return (new google.maps.LatLng(centerX, centerY));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For somone seaching for an answer in dart/flutter 
you can achieve the same by using the code below.

```
 calculateCenter(List<LatLng> points) {
    var longitudes = points.map((i) => i.longitude).toList();
    var latitudes = points.map((i) => i.latitude).toList();

    latitudes.sort();
    longitudes.sort();

    var lowX = latitudes.first;
    var highX = latitudes.last;
    var lowy = longitudes.first;
    var highy = longitudes.last;

    var centerX = lowX + ((highX - lowX) / 2);
    var centerY = lowy + ((highy - lowy) / 2);

    return LatLng(centerX, centerY);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that in the case of a concave polygon the center of the bounding rectangle might be completely outside the polygon. If your polygons might be concaved, I'd recommend using the center of the biggest inscribed circle as the "center" of the polygon. You can see a simple enough algorithm [here (p. 4)](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1212/1212.3193.pdf). If your task is to place a label on the polygon, this will also give the most aesthetically pleasing results (in which case I'd recommend using this method even if your polygons might not be concave).

Answer (score 1):

Getting the center of a polygon with multiple points and setting it on a map

=== Start of Coordinates ===

```
const polyCoords = [
{lat:7.47107077, lng:8.63921547},
{lat:7.46994686, lng:8.63547325},
{lat:7.46309805, lng:8.62589836},
{lat:7.46286821, lng:8.62590313},
{lat:7.45313215, lng:8.60899639},
{lat:7.43740988, lng:8.59334755},
{lat:7.42844009, lng:8.58104324},
{lat:7.41945982, lng:8.56827736},
{lat:7.40859699, lng:8.55323505},
{lat:7.40289497, lng:8.54318237},
{lat:7.392138, lng:8.53482914},
{lat:7.37328196, lng:8.52523136},
{lat:7.35658979, lng:8.52090073},
{lat:7.34258223, lng:8.51121902},
{lat:7.33046389, lng:8.50427532},
{lat:7.31578684, lng:8.49598789},
{lat:7.3011179, lng:8.48839378},
{lat:7.28741598, lng:8.4833231},
{lat:7.27968311, lng:8.4763031},
{lat:7.26344395, lng:8.47150517},
{lat:7.23888779, lng:8.46638584},
{lat:7.21805, lng:8.46258926},
{lat:7.20483398, lng:8.45912266},
{lat:7.18925285, lng:8.45223522},
{lat:7.17993593, lng:8.4470892},
{lat:7.15788603, lng:8.43984985},
{lat:7.13150883, lng:8.43637943},
{lat:7.11252594, lng:8.43324089},
{lat:7.09124422, lng:8.43060589},
{lat:7.06365919, lng:8.42369366},
{lat:7.0361681, lng:8.42277718},
{lat:7.02137899, lng:8.42187691},
{lat:7.00718498, lng:8.41496658},
{lat:6.98336077, lng:8.41237545},
{lat:6.97815323, lng:8.41181469},
{lat:6.96920681, lng:8.41085052},
{lat:6.96485901, lng:8.41038322},
{lat:6.95552588, lng:8.40431404},
{lat:6.94989014, lng:8.40449047},
{lat:6.93937397, lng:8.40481758},
{lat:6.92389822, lng:8.40438938},
{lat:6.90868998, lng:8.40626526},
{lat:6.89626408, lng:8.40878296},
{lat:6.88465405, lng:8.40741062},
{lat:6.88261604, lng:8.4071703},
{lat:6.87496519, lng:8.40522289},
{lat:6.87435913, lng:8.40444374},
{lat:6.874259, lng:8.40431404},
{lat:6.86711407, lng:8.40512753},
{lat:6.85861206, lng:8.40488625},
{lat:6.85695124, lng:8.40484142},
{lat:6.84681988, lng:8.4066267},
{lat:6.83782721, lng:8.40724277},
{lat:6.83494997, lng:8.40681171},
{lat:6.82532978, lng:8.40537834},
{lat:6.81447697, lng:8.40533257},
{lat:6.80816412, lng:8.40398979},
{lat:6.80544186, lng:8.40341187},
{lat:6.80309677, lng:8.40415192},
{lat:6.79915714, lng:8.4053936},
{lat:6.79694414, lng:8.40609169},
{lat:6.79487896, lng:8.40666771},
{lat:6.79399681, lng:8.40691471},
{lat:6.79165602, lng:8.40756893},
{lat:6.79155779, lng:8.40760326},
{lat:6.78247595, lng:8.41095257},
{lat:6.77746391, lng:8.42351627},
{lat:6.76626587, lng:8.45157433},
{lat:6.75096416, lng:8.48992825},
{lat:6.75101185, lng:8.49293423},
{lat:6.75103521, lng:8.49443054},
{lat:6.75106716, lng:8.49638653},
{lat:6.7513752, lng:8.49816227},
{lat:6.75229788, lng:8.5035038},
{lat:6.75233889, lng:8.50374794},
{lat:6.75729084, lng:8.51012325},
{lat:6.75758314, lng:8.51057243},
{lat:6.75847387, lng:8.51194859},
{lat:6.75807714, lng:8.5156126},
{lat:6.7578721, lng:8.51749611},
{lat:6.75769711, lng:8.51795578},
{lat:6.75742817, lng:8.51865578},
{lat:6.75132704, lng:8.97139263},
{lat:6.7482481, lng:8.98090267},
{lat:6.74862814, lng:8.98276329},
{lat:6.74871206, lng:8.9831686},
{lat:6.74890804, lng:8.98458385},
{lat:6.74876881, lng:8.98458672},
{lat:6.74830914, lng:8.98459339},
{lat:6.74822187, lng:8.98898792},
{lat:6.74818087, lng:8.9910574},
{lat:6.74633312, lng:8.99746799},
{lat:6.74763012, lng:8.99746132},
{lat:6.74740887, lng:9.00071144},
{lat:6.74718285, lng:9.00401211},
{lat:6.7468462, lng:9.00896358},
{lat:6.74784899, lng:9.03189945},
{lat:6.74912691, lng:9.04191589},
{lat:6.749506, lng:9.04487896},
{lat:6.7501688, lng:9.06040001},
{lat:6.74998713, lng:9.06665802},
{lat:6.7495532, lng:9.08146954},
{lat:6.75030279, lng:9.10532761},
{lat:6.75147676, lng:9.11876583},
{lat:6.75115299, lng:9.12830734},
{lat:6.751019, lng:9.13230419},
{lat:6.75097609, lng:9.13358688},
{lat:6.75030613, lng:9.15766907},
{lat:6.74956512, lng:9.18568802},
{lat:6.74977493, lng:9.20027924},
{lat:6.75178003, lng:9.20677471},
{lat:6.75207376, lng:9.21673679},
{lat:6.75762796, lng:9.22278786},
{lat:6.76703405, lng:9.22469616},
{lat:6.77835321, lng:9.22522545},
{lat:6.78895092, lng:9.22644424},
{lat:6.80095482, lng:9.22813511},
{lat:6.80803204, lng:9.22840595},
{lat:6.81769705, lng:9.2289257},
{lat:6.8349371, lng:9.2283287},
{lat:6.85686684, lng:9.22915077},
{lat:6.86674404, lng:9.23106098},
{lat:6.87596607, lng:9.23018837},
{lat:6.88755703, lng:9.22863388},
{lat:6.90605688, lng:9.22916317},
{lat:6.92060709, lng:9.22969246},
{lat:6.93092918, lng:9.23265743},
{lat:6.94083691, lng:9.23125458},
{lat:6.96318817, lng:9.23240376},
{lat:6.97901201, lng:9.23571301},
{lat:6.99151802, lng:9.23115253},
{lat:7.00751305, lng:9.22559357},
{lat:7.01615286, lng:9.21457386},
{lat:7.03671312, lng:9.19904041},
{lat:7.04957199, lng:9.18851852},
{lat:7.06313276, lng:9.17939568},
{lat:7.07376099, lng:9.16631126},
{lat:7.09011078, lng:9.15050983},
{lat:7.10480881, lng:9.13908195},
{lat:7.11774111, lng:9.12994957},
{lat:7.12020206, lng:9.12689114},
{lat:7.12678719, lng:9.1187048},
{lat:7.13768578, lng:9.10678005},
{lat:7.14586782, lng:9.09899521},
{lat:7.15596008, lng:9.09561729},
{lat:7.16383696, lng:9.0976162},
{lat:7.16397095, lng:9.09764957},
{lat:7.16446781, lng:9.09777832},
{lat:7.16467285, lng:9.09782982},
{lat:7.16668797, lng:9.0983429},
{lat:7.17027283, lng:9.09925175},
{lat:7.17104816, lng:9.0994482},
{lat:7.17748404, lng:9.11013699},
{lat:7.1852951, lng:9.12178135},
{lat:7.18590498, lng:9.12269306},
{lat:7.19736004, lng:9.14105415},
{lat:7.20605278, lng:9.1508379},
{lat:7.21073914, lng:9.15619564},
{lat:7.22404385, lng:9.17387962},
{lat:7.23505497, lng:9.19177437},
{lat:7.24421883, lng:9.20248795},
{lat:7.25214815, lng:9.2136507},
{lat:7.26130819, lng:9.22829533},
{lat:7.27181292, lng:9.24456787},
{lat:7.27600622, lng:9.25246239},
{lat:7.28409719, lng:9.25877571},
{lat:7.2944541, lng:9.2762022},
{lat:7.29864502, lng:9.28409672},
{lat:7.30395985, lng:9.29338932},
{lat:7.30883694, lng:9.29736137},
{lat:7.31085396, lng:9.29749584},
{lat:7.31294203, lng:9.29763317},
{lat:7.32206106, lng:9.29725742},
{lat:7.32526493, lng:9.30005836},
{lat:7.3387351, lng:9.30434513},
{lat:7.36335707, lng:9.30342197},
{lat:7.3788681, lng:9.30495262},
{lat:7.39461279, lng:9.30810261},
{lat:7.40965986, lng:9.30755138},
{lat:7.43268299, lng:9.30545902},
{lat:7.45160484, lng:9.30448055},
{lat:7.46140003, lng:9.30249405},
{lat:7.47527122, lng:9.291996},
{lat:7.48597622, lng:9.28886032},
{lat:7.49556684, lng:9.29241562},
{lat:7.50426912, lng:9.30243492},
{lat:7.51206589, lng:9.31382847},
{lat:7.51597023, lng:9.32126045},
{lat:7.52583599, lng:9.33729362},
{lat:7.53341389, lng:9.35122871},
{lat:7.54164696, lng:9.35685062},
{lat:7.55055094, lng:9.35993958},
{lat:7.55715799, lng:9.35861778},
{lat:7.56785202, lng:9.35293961},
{lat:7.57442522, lng:9.34260464},
{lat:7.57712793, lng:9.33361816},
{lat:7.58118677, lng:9.32210445},
{lat:7.58320713, lng:9.31334305},
{lat:7.58979607, lng:9.30693436},
{lat:7.5916028, lng:9.30302334},
{lat:7.60486794, lng:9.29872894},
{lat:7.60572386, lng:9.29845142},
{lat:7.60686207, lng:9.29808426},
{lat:7.61690998, lng:9.30256939},
{lat:7.62142801, lng:9.30766106},
{lat:7.62240505, lng:9.30839729},
{lat:7.6258359, lng:9.31074047},
{lat:7.62646914, lng:9.29734325},
{lat:7.62800121, lng:9.29264832},
{lat:7.62849808, lng:9.29112339},
{lat:7.62477303, lng:9.27168179},
{lat:7.61906385, lng:9.26338196},
{lat:7.61789513, lng:9.26168156},
{lat:7.60666084, lng:9.260952},
{lat:7.60124397, lng:9.26060104},
{lat:7.60034084, lng:9.25955677},
{lat:7.59277201, lng:9.25081539},
{lat:7.58999205, lng:9.24243736},
{lat:7.58469677, lng:9.22647762},
{lat:7.57617283, lng:9.20398521},
{lat:7.57207108, lng:9.18593216},
{lat:7.57107019, lng:9.18152714},
{lat:7.56439877, lng:9.16621494},
{lat:7.55862188, lng:9.14605904},
{lat:7.55898905, lng:9.13870907},
{lat:7.55946493, lng:9.12918186},
{lat:7.55989313, lng:9.12065315},
{lat:7.55908394, lng:9.11564445},
{lat:7.55753183, lng:9.10603333},
{lat:7.55615616, lng:9.0975132},
{lat:7.55674982, lng:9.09182739},
{lat:7.55695581, lng:9.08985138},
{lat:7.55813408, lng:9.07858467},
{lat:7.55744982, lng:9.05847168},
{lat:7.55736303, lng:9.05593491},
{lat:7.55961514, lng:9.04537582},
{lat:7.56139517, lng:9.03702545},
{lat:7.56247616, lng:9.03288078},
{lat:7.5634079, lng:9.02930832},
{lat:7.56566381, lng:9.02066135},
{lat:7.56515789, lng:9.00748539},
{lat:7.5639658, lng:9.00404358},
{lat:7.56356478, lng:9.00404358},
{lat:7.56289005, lng:9.00404358},
{lat:7.56242323, lng:9.00015068},
{lat:7.56232119, lng:8.99929619},
{lat:7.56194496, lng:8.99821568},
{lat:7.56198788, lng:8.99778271},
{lat:7.56215, lng:8.99696159},
{lat:7.56281996, lng:8.96886539},
{lat:7.55899286, lng:8.95738316},
{lat:7.55724001, lng:8.95211983},
{lat:7.55969477, lng:8.93246746},
{lat:7.55676603, lng:8.90829468},
{lat:7.55125523, lng:8.89593029},
{lat:7.54641199, lng:8.88194084},
{lat:7.54488802, lng:8.87319756},
{lat:7.54288197, lng:8.86331367},
{lat:7.53791094, lng:8.85578632},
{lat:7.53442907, lng:8.84015846},
{lat:7.52946901, lng:8.83331966},
{lat:7.5268302, lng:8.82713699},
{lat:7.52469683, lng:8.8237114},
{lat:7.52377796, lng:8.80965614},
{lat:7.522964, lng:8.80752277},
{lat:7.51968002, lng:8.79888344},
{lat:7.51792288, lng:8.79014683},
{lat:7.51585579, lng:8.77657032},
{lat:7.5152092, lng:8.76504707},
{lat:7.51339722, lng:8.75284863},
{lat:7.50989103, lng:8.73583889},
{lat:7.50696516, lng:8.72619915},
{lat:7.50269794, lng:8.71934986},
{lat:7.50024414, lng:8.69586086},
{lat:7.48745108, lng:8.69007874},
{lat:7.48527384, lng:8.68388939},
{lat:7.48022795, lng:8.67174816},
{lat:7.475317, lng:8.65337563},
{lat:7.47107077, lng:8.63921547}];
```

=== End of Coordinates ===

```
// Construct the polygon.
  const polygong= new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polyCoords,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
  });
  
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  polyCoords.forEach(function(coord, index)
  {
     bounds.extend(coord);
  });

  //Note: "map" object already set and initialized elsewhere but not shown in code snippet to reduce verbosity 
  map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version of getting center of polygon. `mPoints` is array of `latitude` and `longitude`.

```
val bounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()

for(i in 0 until mPoints.size) {
    val point = LatLng(mPoints[i].latitude, mPoints[i].longitude)

    bounds.include(point)
}
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(bounds.build().center))
```