# Google map js api version 3 polygon infowindow on wrong position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have this block of code inside a loop:

```
      var points = [new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1),
          new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon1),
          new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon2),
          new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon2),
          new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1)
          ];
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1));
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon1));
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon2));
      bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon2));
      var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        paths: points,
                        strokeColor: "#f33f00",
                        strokeOpacity: 1,
                        strokeWeight: 1,
                        fillColor: "#ff0000",
                        fillOpacity: 0.2
                    });

    var x1 = Math.min(lon1,lon2);
    var y1 = Math.min(lat1,lat2);
    var x2 = Math.max(lon1,lon2);
    var y2 = Math.max(lat1,lat2);
    var x = x1 + ((x2 - x1) / 2);
    var y = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / 2);
    var cp = new google.maps.LatLng(y,x);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    infoWindow.setPosition(cp);
                    infoWindow.setContent(html);

   google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, "click", function() {
                        infoWindow.open(map);
                    });

                    polygon.setMap(map);
```

My problem is when I click each of the polygons, the infowindow opens on the same position for all the polygons.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was, set the map globally, replace the block of code with a call to a function outside the loop that does the same work, like this:

```
function createPolygon(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, html)
{
     var points = [new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1),
      new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon1),
      new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon2),
      new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon2),
      new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1)
      ];
  bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1));
  bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon1));
  bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon2));
  bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon2));
  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    paths: points,
                    strokeColor: "#f33f00",
                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                    strokeWeight: 1,
                    fillColor: "#ff0000",
                    fillOpacity: 0.2
                });

var x1 = Math.min(lon1,lon2);
var y1 = Math.min(lat1,lat2);
var x2 = Math.max(lon1,lon2);
var y2 = Math.max(lat1,lat2);
var x = x1 + ((x2 - x1) / 2);
var y = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / 2);
var cp = new google.maps.LatLng(y,x);
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                infoWindow.setPosition(cp);
                infoWindow.setContent(html);

 google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, "click", function() {
                    infoWindow.open(map);
                });

                polygon.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: a Polygon can have more than 4 sides, then how one can get the center of this in order to put the infowindow there?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081021/how-to-get-the-center-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3 by furiozo

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the infoWindow-object on every loop.

Store the properties related to the infoWindow(cp,html) inside the polygon-objects and call `setPosition()` and `setContent()` inside the click-function by using the stored properties.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I tried doing these too: `
     
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html, position: cp});
                    
AND 

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    

   google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, "click", function() {
                        
  infoWindow.setPosition(cp);
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
  infoWindow.open(map);
    });

                    polygon.setMap(map);
`

But they didn't seem to work.