# How do I calculate the center of a polygon in Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have drawn a polygon on google map using several Latitude,Longitude points.But now I need to place a marker at the center of the polygon for which I need the center coordinates.How do I calculate the center point.

**Below is the code for adding polygons on map:**

```
for (Warning w : warningsList) {
            // Instantiates a new Polygon object and adds points
            PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
            List<PolyPoints> pp = w.getPolyPoints();
            for (PolyPoints p : pp) {
                rectOptions.add(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(p.getLatitude()),
                        Double.valueOf(p.getLongitude())));
            }

                mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.GREEN)
                        .fillColor(Color.RED).strokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH));

        }
```

I found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081021/how-to-get-the-center-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3) which has been answered but thats for JavaScript Api.Is their any way of using the same solution in my case?

Comment: Is there any code you can provide us with?

Comment: @kolonelpeteruk I have added some code which shows how I am adding polygons on map.

Comment: What kind of center do you want to implement? Center of gravity? Center of bounds? Which one have you tried implementing?

Comment: @MaciejGórski Center of bounds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below is the code which I am using now to find the center of polygon:-

```
public static double[] centroid(List<PolyPoints> points) {
        double[] centroid = { 0.0, 0.0 };

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            centroid[0] += points.get(i).getLatitude();
            centroid[1] += points.get(i).getLongitude();
        }

        int totalPoints = points.size();
        centroid[0] = centroid[0] / totalPoints;
        centroid[1] = centroid[1] / totalPoints;

        return centroid;
    }
```

Answer (score 32):

Below code I am using to find the center point of the polygon. its working for me too

```
private LatLng getPolygonCenterPoint(ArrayList<LatLng> polygonPointsList){
        LatLng centerLatLng = null;
        Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder(); 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < polygonPointsList.size() ; i++) 
        {          
            builder.include(polygonPointsList.get(i));
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        centerLatLng =  bounds.getCenter();

        return centerLatLng;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private static LatLng getCenterOfPolygon(List<LatLng> latLngList) {
        double[] centroid = {0.0, 0.0};
        for (int i = 0; i < latLngList.size(); i++) {
            centroid[0] += latLngList.get(i).latitude;
            centroid[1] += latLngList.get(i).longitude;
        }
        int totalPoints = latLngList.size();
        return new LatLng(centroid[0] / totalPoints, centroid[1] / totalPoints);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using two methods. but it works with any shape...

```
private static double area(ArrayList<LatLng> arr) {
    double area=0;
    int nPts = arr.size();
    int j=nPts-1;
    LatLng p1; LatLng p2;
    for (int i=0;i<nPts;j=i++) {

        p1=arr.get(i); p2=arr.get(j);
        area+=p1.latitude*p2.longitude;
        area-=p1.longitude*p2.latitude;
    }
    area/=2;

    return area;
};

public static LatLng Centroid (ArrayList<LatLng> pts) {
    int nPts = pts.size();
    double x=0; double y=0;
    double f;
    int j=nPts-1;
    LatLng p1; LatLng p2;

    for (int i=0;i<nPts;j=i++) {
        p1=pts.get((i)); p2=pts.get(j);
        f=p1.latitude*p2.longitude-p2.latitude*p1.longitude;
        x+=(p1.latitude+p2.latitude)*f;
        y+=(p1.longitude+p2.longitude)*f;
    }

    f=area(pts)*6;

    return new LatLng(x/f, y/f);
};
```

Simply call the Centroid Method within your class and pass in your LatLng Array as a parameter. make sure the Array list you are passing is LatLng Array List

LatLng polyCentroid = Centroid(list);

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
 .position(polyCentroid));

Answer (score 0):

```
Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the code snippet provided and it's not complete too. Making an object only doesn't make sense here. Please provide the full code with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [blogpost](https://moduscreate.com/blog/placing-markers-inside-polygons-with-google-maps/), i have created a Kotlin version.
I implemented it as a `Polygon` extension.

```
package com.example.diman.googlemapsplayground

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon
import com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil
import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil

/**
 * Find approximate center of a polygon.
 * Reference: https://moduscreate.com/blog/placing-markers-inside-polygons-with-google-maps/
 *
 * Algorithm:
 * If the bounding box center point is inside the polygon, return center point.
 * Otherwise, sample points at fixed percentages of the bounding box’s height North and South of the center point.
 * Sample points at fixed percentages of the bounding box’s width East and West of the center point.
 * Stop when we find the first point that is inside the area of the polygon, and drop the marker there.
 */
fun Polygon.getApproximateCenter(): LatLng {
  // Calc bounds first
  val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.builder()
  points.forEach {
    boundsBuilder.include(it)
  }
  val polygonBounds = boundsBuilder.build()

  val centerPoint = polygonBounds.center

  // Center point is inside the polygon, return it
  if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(centerPoint, points, true)) {
    return centerPoint
  }

  // Center point is out of bounds
  // Sample points at fixed percentages of the bounding box’s width East and West of the center point.
  val maxSearchSteps = 10
  var testPos: LatLng = centerPoint

  // Calculate NorthWest point so we can work out height of polygon NW->SE
  val northWest = LatLng(polygonBounds.northeast.latitude, polygonBounds.southwest.longitude)

  // Work out how tall and wide the bounds are and what our search
  // increment will be
  val boundsHeight = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(northWest, polygonBounds.southwest)
  val heightIncr = boundsHeight / maxSearchSteps

  val boundsWidth = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(northWest, polygonBounds.northeast)
  val widthIncr = boundsWidth / maxSearchSteps

  // Expand out from Centroid and find a point within polygon at
  // 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees
  for (n in 1..maxSearchSteps) {
    // Test point North of Centroid
    testPos = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(
        centerPoint,
        (heightIncr * n),
        0.0
    )
    if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(testPos, points, true)) {
      break
    }

    // Test point East of Centroid
    testPos = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(
        centerPoint,
        (widthIncr * n),
        90.0
    )
    if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(testPos, points, true)) {
      break
    }

    // Test point South of Centroid
    testPos = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(
        centerPoint,
        (heightIncr * n),
        180.0
    )
    if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(testPos, points, true)) {
      break
    }

    // Test point West of Centroid
    testPos = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(
        centerPoint,
        (widthIncr * n),
        270.0
    )
    if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(testPos, points, true)) {
      break
    }
  }

  return testPos
}
```

Note, add `PolyUtil` and `SphericalUtil` by adding to gradle:

`implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'`