# Google Maps: How to combine a polygon with map.fitBounds()?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Okay, I'm feeling fairly dense for not being able to figure the last part of this out, so hopefully somebody can show me the last piece of the puzzle. I have one example of a polygon that always needs to be visible and another example that uses `map.fitBounds()` with the same area defined so it IS always visible. The last step is displaying that polygon overlaid on the `map.fitBounds()` map.

```
    var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(41.49623534616764, -88.209228515625);
    var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(42.64810165693524, -86.4019775390625);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Essentially, the code above needs to either replace or supplement the center functionality, which is what I don't get:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    navigationControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.845644,-87.766685),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var serviceAreaSealMaster;
```

I recreated it on codepen: http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/EbmJi

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the center of a polygon in google maps v3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081021/how-to-get-the-center-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3).  Get the bounds of your polygon, call map.fitBounds with that bounds.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks, I pretty much figured that was the case, but I couldn't figure out where to add it to make it work. Fortunately a fresh set of eyes helped me solve yesterday's density issue. I forked my original codepen with the solution if anyone is interested: http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/Dirfn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, geocodezip's confirmation that I was on the right track and a fresh set of eyes solved the problem and I posted the solution in a forked codepen  http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/Dirfn

(***Nevermind, the following is no longer an issue:***)
PS: In case anyone looks at that and wonders why it doesn't appear to be resizing correctly in a few instances, I'm pretty sure that its the boundary that I defined not being as accurate as it needs to be. I'll be fixing that next, but I didn't want to confuse anyone that might see it before then...