# Center map between three markers via Basic Google Maps Placemarks [WordPress]

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, location, google-maps-markers

1. How can I center map between three markers?
2. How can I range markers?
   When I print them like this:

   [bgmp-map placemark="27" zoom="15" width="730" height="250"]

   [bgmp-list]

   [bgmp-map placemark="92" zoom="15" width="730" height="250"]

   [bgmp-list]

   [bgmp-map placemark="96" zoom="15" width="730" height="250"]

   [bgmp-list]

they comes on the page in this order: 92 96 27.
WHat can I do to show them in order 27 92 96?

Thanx a lot in advance!

Comment: When you say you want to "center map between three markers", do you mean that you want the map to be focused on the point that is at the center of 3 markers?

Comment: @not_a_bot yes, sir.

Comment: If you were trying to get the center in just Google Maps, you could set the coordinates of the markers as points of a polygon and get the center of that as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3082334/4241842), then set that as the center of the map, but I'm not sure how to translate that through Wordpress. I'm also unclear on what you mean by ranging the markers, could you post a picture of what it looks like and how it should look?

Comment: This is how it looks right [now](http://joxi.ru/BA0p4gnfa8gPAy), and this is how I try to make it [work](http://joxi.ru/MAj1MW7fJ3V12e)