# finding polygon center google map api 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I want to find the center of a polygon in google map, I tried several solutions however none of them worked correctly for right triangle polygon here is example code:

```
var path = new Array(new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1), new google.maps.LatLng(1, 10), new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10), new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1));

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, 9),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: path,
    map: map
});

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i=0; i<polygon.getPath().length; i++) {

    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(path[i].lat(), path[i].lng());
    bounds.extend(point);
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: bounds.getCenter().lat(),
    lng: bounds.getCenter().lng()
  },
  map: this.map,
  title: "Hello World!"
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

I used `google.maps.LatLngBounds();` for finding cneter of the triangle and mark the center in the map however the result center is not actually true center of the triangle, [jsfiddle example of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/fn3nbvuy/290/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fn3nbvuy).
I used another solution [which is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081021/how-to-get-the-center-of-a-polygon-in-google-maps-v3/16124729#161) for finding the center of the polygon but that won't work either so is there any other solution for finding an accurate center of polygons regardless of polygon type?

Comment: What do you mean by the "true" center?

Comment: if you see jsfiddle example you can see that marker isn't exactly in the center of the triangle.I mean bounds.center() is not the center point of the triangle

Comment: So you want the [centroid of the polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid), not the center of the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

points is array of polygon points,call getCenter to get coordinates of center.

```
var points = [[1,1],[1,10],[10,10]];
function getCenter(){
    var sumX = 0, sumY = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
        var point = points[i];
        var x = point[0];
        var y = point[1];
        sumX += x;
        sumY += y;
    }
    return {x:sumX / points.length,y:sumY / points.length};
}

var centerOfPoints = getCenter();
```

Comment: Thanks. I am working with Angular Google maps and using dataLayer component.

Answer (score 0):

To get the center of a Polygon, rather than an average of all the points try this

```
/**
 * Calculates the center point of a polygon.
 *
 * @param {google.maps.Polygon} polygon - The polygon object.
 * @returns {google.maps.LatLng} - The center point of the polygon.
 */
function getPolygonCenter(polygon) {
  const path = polygon.getPath();
  let latSum = 0;
  let lngSum = 0;

  path.forEach(function (point) {
    latSum += point.lat();
    lngSum += point.lng();
  });

  const centerLat = latSum / path.getLength();
  const centerLng = lngSum / path.getLength();

  return new google.maps.LatLng(centerLat, centerLng);
}
```

This is more robust for mercator distortions as it uses Google wizardry instead.