# How to add text/label to my map in angular -typescript without using marker?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I am using agm-map in angular. I need to add one label/text to the centre of my polygon in map.
How can I implement that in **Typescript** without using marker?

I’ve tried to do it using MapLabel Utility. Take a look at below code.

```
label: new MapLabel({
    text: result[index].name,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(object.lat, object.lng),
    fontSize: 10,
    fontColor: #000,
    labelInBackground: true,
    strokeColor: #000,
    map: map
})
```

I have also referred below link
https://codepen.io/adg29/pen/reGaPd

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get first the coordinates of the center of the polygon and use that as the value for your label coordinates. To get the center of the polygon, I followed the answer from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3082334/11025839) then used the coordinates as the value of  *ll* in the labelOverlay.

To explain:
First, I noticed that you created the labelOverlay before the polygon. So to get the coordinate of the center of the polygon, you need to move the polygon before the labelOverlay.

Then, you will add the code snippet from the SO post to pass each point of the polygon to a LatLngBounds object through the extend() method.

Get the center of the bounds and used it as the value of the ll in your labelOverlay.

The following is a snippet of how the code should look like. You can also see the [working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e2vfp0wh/).

```
 // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < triangleCoords.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend(triangleCoords[i]);
}

var polygonCenter = bounds.getCenter();

var overlay1 = new LabelOverlay({
    ll      : polygonCenter,
    //minBox    : box,

    minBoxH     : 0.346,
    minBoxW     : 1.121,

    maxBoxH     : 0.09,
    maxBoxW     : 0.3,

    //className : 'small',

    debugBoxes  : true,
    debugVisibility : true,

    maxZoom     : 10,
    minZoom     : 6,
    label       : "Hello world",
    map     : map
});
```

Comment: I am unable to use this code in my typescript file for adding label. Can you help me with that?

Comment: "Cannot find LabelOverlay" getting this error when I tried to implement it in typescript.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your typescript code?